# Collapse vector to string of characters with respective numbers of consequtive occurences

Tags: r

I would like to collapse a CIGAR vector to a CIGAR string.  By CIGAR vector to String I mean the following:

I want a function that converts:

```
cigar.vector = c("M", "M", "I", "I", "M", "I", "", "M", "D", "D", "M", "I", "D", "M", "I")
```

to this:

```
cigar.string = "2M2I1M1I1M2D1M1I1D1M1I"
```

and viceversa.

Note that there is a "" (empty character), that does not count.  thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`rle` seems the obvious choice here:

```
rcv <- rle(cigar.vector[cigar.vector!=""])
paste0(rcv$lengths,rcv$values,collapse="")
#[1] "2M2I1M1I1M2D1M1I1D1M1I"
```

If you want to get fancy, you could also exploit the fact that `rle` gives a list of length 2:

```
paste(do.call(rbind,rle(cigar.vector[cigar.vector!=""])),collapse="")
#[1] "2M2I1M1I1M2D1M1I1D1M1I"
```

Going backwards will be impossible if only given the result (assign above to `result`), as it has lost information for the `""` cases. Excluding those cases, you can get close enough with something like:

```
backwards <- rep(
  unlist(strsplit(result,"\\d+"))[-1],
  as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(result,"[^0-9]")))
)
identical(cigar.vector[cigar.vector!=""],backwards)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @thelatemail thanks a lot, works perfect.  Jilber thanks to you too, I saw your answer as well :-)

Comment: I've got to get some momentum behind my campaign to add "if in doubt, use rle"  to the `fortunes` file :-)