# Speed-up data.table group by using multiple cores and parallel programming

Tags: r, data.table, mclapply

I have a large code and the aggregation step is the current bottleneck in terms of speed.

In my code I'd like to speed-up the data grouping step to be faster.  A SNOTE (simple non trivial example) of my data looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
a = sample(1:10000000, 50000000, replace = TRUE)
b = sample(c("3m","2m2d2m","3m2d1i3s2d","5m","4m","9m","1m"), 50000000, replace = TRUE)
d = sample(c("3m","2m2d2m","3m2d1i3s2d","5m","4m","9m","1m"), 50000000, replace = TRUE)
e = a
dt = data.table(a = a, b = b, d = d, e = e)
system.time(c.dt <- dt[,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[1], by=a)])
   user  system elapsed 
 60.107   3.143  63.534
```

This is quite fast for such large data example but in my case I am still looking for further speed-up. In my case I have multiple cores so I am almost sure there must be a way to use such computational capability.

I am open to changing my data type to a data.frame, or idata.frame objects (in theory idata.frame are supposedly faster than data.frames).

I did some research and seems the plyr package has some parallel capabilities that could be helpful but I am still struggling on how to do it for the grouping I am trying to do.  In [another SO post they discuss some of these ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685492/r-speeding-up-group-by-operations?lq=1).  I am still unsure on how much more I'd achieve with this parallelization since it uses the foreach function. In my experience the [foreach function](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2013/08/the-wonders-of-foreach/) is not a good idea for millions of fast operations because the communication effort between cores ends up slowing down the parallelization effort.

Comment: Please be more specific about what the words "concatenate" and "aggregate" mean. The functions these brings to mind are 3: `list`, `c`, and `paste`. And what is the function of that code. Are we extracting columns from dataframes or working on data.tables? What are the structures of 'block.read.parent.cigar' and other input variables .....  explain this problem better! (Apparently someone else agrees. That's not my downvote.)

Comment: @Dwin, thanks!  I am not sure if I clarified enough in the Q, but the basic Q is how to speed up an aggregating operation for a large data table like the one in the example above.  Also to have in mind that i can use multiple cores so there may be some smart paralelization ideas that could speed-up such operation considerably.  Hope this helps, I added an example

Comment: I'm not downvoting either, but it seems like storing your data in this way (with character vectors) will generally be slow, and concatenating them will only slow you down further (unless you're exporting for use in other software), since you'll need to break down the strings again and again for analysis. Probably, you should be using a specialized package for cigars...I don't know anything about these, but you were already directed to one in an earlier question...http://stackoverflow.com/q/18969698/1191259

Comment: I didn't downvote. But the reason I would do is you haven't provided any information about the data. If `read.index` is a row index then of course grouping every row into a row by itself is going to be slow. You'll be calling `paste` millions of times. Did you use `Rprof`? Did you use `verbose=TRUE`? And you're using words like "too slow" without giving numbers. In fact, I've talked myself into downvoting it now. It can be reversed if you improve the question.

Comment: @MatthewDowle thanks, did you see the toy example?  From the toy example is clear that the read index is an ID and not a row index.  It is true that on average a given read index may appear a few times, so in practice I am calling paste millions of times, and there's the point:  How could I use MULTIPLE CORES to SPEED-UP such operation? How can I use the power of parallel computation to make such line run much faster?  Maybe there's a way to do it, or maybe one has to change the code dramatically in order to do it.  Not sure about the answer, that is why I asked this Q.

Comment: @MatthewDowle with respect to the wording I think you are right, no need to say super slow or stuff like that since it's all relative to the data.table structure that one is using, I did not mean to criticize data.table, in fact I love that package and I use it regularly I was just looking for ways to speed up that line in my code.

Comment: No problem.  The question is improving.  If you make a reproducible large example, and state the time you get, then I'll take a look (and maybe others will be attracted too). Show a small n=3 example and then say "set n=1e6 and it takes 2 hours for me, is there a faster way?". Something like that.

Comment: @MatthewDowle thanks, I will prepare an example and post it later today, though I realized a major bug in my code I was loading way too large data tables in my code and was using 300 GB of RAM... changing the code and getting back to this Q later today... thanks a lot!

Comment: Hah, we've all been there. If that turns out to be it, just delete the question.

Comment: @MattDowle I just updated the question with an example.  Now I am reading my huge data in chunks of smaller data so no overuse of the RAM anymore.  It'd still help me to speed up this part but not sure how to do it.

Comment: @Dnaiel That's now a great question. +1. I'll try and take a look. Some answerers just have new question feeds I guess, so to get more attention it might be an idea to offer a bounty.

Comment: @MattDowle thanks a lot, I am glad I improved such confusing Q :-) Not sure how great it is but that's the problem I am dealing with.  I am learning more on how to ask better questions so it's good for me.

Comment: @Dnaiel, are you sure that the "A SNOTE" you provided is giving you the output you expect.  Have you tested it?  Also, are you sure about that `S` in `SNOTE` ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have multiple cores available to you, why not leverage the fact that you can quickly filter & group rows in a data.table using its key:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4)


setkey(dt, "a")

finalRowOrderMatters = FALSE # FALSE can be faster
foreach(x=unique(dt[["a"]]), .combine="rbind", .inorder=finalRowOrderMatters) %dopar% 
     dt[.(x) ,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[[1]])]
```

---

Note that if the number of unique groups (ie `length(unique(a))` ) is relatively small, it will be faster to drop the `.combine` argument, get the results back in a list, then call `rbindlist` on the results.  In my testing on two cores & 8GB RAM, the threshold was at about 9,000 unique values.  Here is what I used to benchmark:

```
# (otion a)
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
# ------- #
  foreach(x=unique(dt[["a"]]), .combine="rbind", .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% 
     dt[.(x) ,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[[1]])]
# ------- #
}))), 3) 
# [1]  1.243 elapsed for N ==  1,000
# [1] 11.540 elapsed for N == 10,000, length(unique(dt[["a"]])) == 8617
# [1] 57.404 elapsed for N == 50,000



# (otion b)
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
# ------- #
    results <- 
      foreach(x=unique(dt[["a"]])) %dopar% 
         dt[.(x) ,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[[1]])]
    rbindlist(results)
# ------- #
}))), 3)
# [1]  1.117 elapsed for N ==  1,000
# [1] 10.567 elapsed for N == 10,000, length(unique(dt[["a"]])) == 8617
# [1] 76.613 elapsed for N == 50,000


## And used the following to create the dt
N <- 5e4
set.seed(1)
a = sample(1:N, N*2, replace = TRUE)
b = sample(c("3m","2m2d2m","3m2d1i3s2d","5m","4m","9m","1m"), N*2, replace = TRUE)
d = sample(c("3m","2m2d2m","3m2d1i3s2d","5m","4m","9m","1m"), N*2, replace = TRUE)
e = a
dt = data.table(a = a, b = b, d = d, e = e, key="a")
```

Comment: Does each sub process need to copy over the full data.table, or do they all access the "main" data.table object?

Answer (score 14):

Can you parallelize aggregation with `data.table`? Yes.

Is it worth it? **NO**. This is a key point that the previous answer failed to highlight.

As [Matt Dowle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403310/matt-dowle) explains in [data.table and parallel computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759905/data-table-and-parallel-computing), copies ("chunks") need to be made before being distributed when running operations in parallel. This slows things down. In some cases, when you *cannot* use `data.table` (e.g. running many linear regressions), it is worth splitting up tasks between cores. But not aggregation — at least when `data.table` is involved.

In short (and until proven otherwise), *aggregate using `data.table`* and stop worrying about potential speed increases using `doMC`. `data.table` is already blazing fast compared to anything else available when it comes to aggregation — even if it's not multicore!

---

Here are some benchmarks you can run for yourself comparing `data.table` internal aggregation using `by` with `foreach` and `mclapply`. 
The results are listed first.

```
#-----------------------------------------------

# TL;DR FINAL RESULTS (Best to Worst)
# 3 replications, N = 10000:
# (1)  0.007 -- data.table using `by`
# (2)  3.548 -- mclapply with rbindlist
# (3)  5.557 -- foreach with rbindlist
# (4)  5.959 -- foreach with .combine = "rbind"
# (5) 14.029 -- lapply

# ----------------------------------------------

library(data.table)

## And used the following to create the dt
N <- 1e4
set.seed(1)
a = sample(1:N, N*2, replace = TRUE)
b = sample(c("3m","2m2d2m","3m2d1i3s2d","5m","4m","9m","1m"), N*2, replace = TRUE)
d = sample(c("3m","2m2d2m","3m2d1i3s2d","5m","4m","9m","1m"), N*2, replace = TRUE)
e = a
dt = data.table(a = a, b = b, d = d, e = e, key="a")
setkey(dt, "a")

# TEST AGGREGATION WITHOUT PARALLELIZATION ---------------------------
## using data.tables `by` to aggregate
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
    dt[,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[1], by=a)]
}))), 3)
# [1] 0.007 elapsed for N == 10,000, length(unique(dt[["a"]])) == 8617

## using `lapply`
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
    results <- lapply(unique(dt[["a"]]), function(x) {
        dt[.(x), list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[1])]
    })
    rbindlist(results)
}))), 3)
# [1] 14.029 elapsed for N == 10,000

# USING `mclapply` FORKING ---------------------------------
## use mclapply
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
    results <- mclapply(unique(dt[["a"]]),
    function(x) {
        dt[.(x), list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[[1]])]
    }, mc.cores=4)
    rbindlist(results)
}))), 3)
# [1] 3.548 elapsed for N == 10,000


# PARALLELIZATION USING `doMC` PACKAGE ---------------------------------
library(doMC)
mc = 4
registerDoMC(cores=mc)
getDoParWorkers()
# [1] 4

## (option a) by Ricardo Saporta
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
    foreach(x=unique(dt[["a"]]), .combine="rbind", .inorder=FALSE) %dopar%
    dt[.(x) ,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[[1]])]
}))), 3)
# [1] 5.959 elapsed for N == 10,000

## (option b) by Ricardo Saporta
round(rowMeans(replicate(3, system.time({
    results <-
      foreach(x=unique(dt[["a"]])) %dopar%
        dt[.(x) ,list(b = paste(b, collapse=""), d = paste(d, collapse=""), e = e[[1]])]
    rbindlist(results)
}))), 3)
# [1] 5.557 elapsed for N == 10,000

registerDoSEQ()
getDoParWorkers()
# [1] 1
```