# Fastest way to remove this list-wise for loop?

Tags: r, performance, list, for-loop

Using R:

I have a list of vectors with length n, that correspond to a vector of ids, also of length n. so there are m id's in each vector in the list. I also have a vector of values, length m:

```
L1 = c(1,65,23)
L2 = c(1,23,45)
L3 = c(45,23)
L4 = c(45,65)

V2 = list(L1,L2,L3,L4)

IDs = c(1, 23, 45, 65)
Values = c(400, 500, 100, 150)
dat = data.frame(IDs, Values)
```

I would like to subtract each value from the corresponding (by index) list.
In a loop this would be something like:

```
testFun = function(dat){
        y = list()
        for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
        y[[i]] = dat$Value[i] - dat$Value[which(dat$IDs %in% V2[[i]])]

        }
    return(y)
    }
testFun(dat)
```

Basically, this works, but does not scale well. 
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what is `y`? (your example is not reproducible)

Comment: @mnel y = list()
sorry for the omission

Comment: note, there is no need for `which` in your `[  ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach is to keep the results in tablur form.  Here is a data.table solution

```
# convert your data to data.table
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat, key="IDs")

DT[, Values - DT[.(V2[[i]])]$Values , by=list(i=seq(nrow(DT)))]
    i   V1
 1: 1    0
 2: 1  250
 3: 1 -100
 4: 2  100
 5: 2    0
 6: 2  400
 7: 3    0
 8: 3 -400
 9: 4   50
10: 4    0
```

Comment: or `DT[, list(list(Values - DT[.(V2[[i]])]$Values)) , by=list(i=seq(nrow(DT)))]` to keep it as list.

Comment: @menl, yep good point.  I think there might be advantage to using `RES[.(3), _expr_]`  (where `RES` is the results output).

Comment: Would this scale? In the dataset I have 175,000 IDs, each assocated to a V1 vector with mean length 500

Comment: @Sarobinson, only one way to really find out :)     Not only should it scale, but it should be much much faster than using `%in%`.   That being said, you should benchmark this method with MNEL's suggestion.

Comment: OK, so the data.table solution is faster than the loop, but is still very slow (~5mins). Is there another way? mcapply maybe?

Comment: 5 minutes is a long time?  But yes, you can use `foreach` See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19205276/1492421

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `data.table` solution

```
DT <- data.table(dat, key = 'IDs')

DT[, col3 := vector(mode='list',length = nrow(DT))]

for (i in seq_along(V2)){
   set(DT, i = i, j = 'col3', value = list(list(DT[i,Values] - DT[.(V2[[i]])][['Values']])))
}
```

Note that you are creating a vector of length 175000, 175000 times. With your current data setup and the outcome you want, this will  be your limiting factor for time.